# Output full block data

Tags: go-ethereum, blocks

I am looking to get an example block's full data so I can examine what information is available within it.

The main questions I am looking to answer are:

- Is there actual tx info within the block or just tx hashes?
- Is there any way to derive internal txs and map them to a related tx within a block besides executing/confirming the block?

Thanks!